# TypeScript add global components FontAwesome in Vue Project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, font-awesome

Hi I'm new with TypeScript , I want to add the FontAwesome icons into my Vue App. I Forgot to tell that it's a project with Vue 3

This is my `main.ts` :

```
import Vue, { createApp } from 'vue';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import App from './App.vue';

library.add(faUserSecret);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon); // This line generate an error

createApp(App).use(router).use(store).mount('#app');
```

The error is :
[image]

How can I setup my fontawesome component globally ? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import { Vue, createApp } from 'vue';`?

Comment: Same error with `import { Vue, createApp } from 'vue';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cleanest solution it is posible to chain.

```
createApp(App).component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon).mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using new Vue(), we now need to import the new createApp method.
so below line will generate error:

```
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon); // This line generate an error
```

As per Vue 3 replace vue.component to app.component :

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```